# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship in core data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to build a relationship between two objects on a background thread and Core Data keeps firing off "llegal attempt to establish a relationship"

Here is some basic code of what is happening:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
 @synchronized(self) {
  return persistentStoreCoordinator;
 }
 return nil;
}
- (void)startBackgroundTask {
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTask:) withObject:managedObjectID];
}
- (void)backgroundTask:(NSManagedObjectID *)pManagedObjectID {
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
 [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
 NSManagedObject *object = [managedObjectContext objectWithID:pManagedObjectID];
 NSManagedObject *childObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ChildObject" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 [object setValue:childObject forKey:@"childObject"];
 [managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

I'm correctly creating a "thread-safe" background thread managed object context and fetching the object via the object id so unsure why it's not working.

Also compare the [object managedObjectContext] contexts results in a "true" equal condition.

Any help greatly appreciated,

-Robert

Answer (score 0):

This was rather stupid.

In my code versus this example I put up I was creating a Transient Object and not inserting it into the background managed object context.